# flash content on html 5 native app on android and ios

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex, cordova

How can we run swf file inside native app of android and Ios. I want to run swf inside html5 app. Presently I am using PhoneGap or Cardova for this app.

Is there any option for html5 than please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Especially not on iOS that does **not** have any flash support at all.

Comment: I have run flash on android using html5 cordova of apache by overriding the function in webview but not tried on ios because i dont have xcode or mac. So want to know that, Can we run flash on ios also?

Comment: No, flash can't be used on iOS. Your only choice seems to be Adobe AIR really.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Google Swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/)? It allows to convert SWF into HTML5.

If you want to use SWF for playing animation on HTML5, you also can use [LWF](http://gree.github.io/lwf/) ([an animation sample on HTML5](http://gree.github.io/lwf-demo/html5/lwf-loader/sample3.html)), it works well on Android and iOS.

Comment: if we are working on audio, video conferencing app?? than Is it possible that same functionality will work,  after converting using LWF?

Comment: No, LWF is only for animation. AFAIK there are no solutions for such SWF except Flash Player, Flash Player doesn't support iOS at all, Flash Player no longer supports Android any more.

Comment: Adobe AIR is the last hope, but you can't use Cordova with it.

Comment: we are using adobe air right now. But was thinking to make app bit more light wight that y thinking about about html5. Because market is crying for html5 only for mobile devices. But html5 does not provide any solution of audio video conferencing.

Comment: So you have to consider using native plugins of Cordova for Android and iOS, such like https://github.com/opentok/PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

you can use Puffin browser for IOS and Android,
works very well for all flash swf, AS1/AS2/AS3 included